# Run Custom Module as Service instead of launching a WinForms application

Tags: kofax

I created a custom module for Kofax. This module is a WinForms application with a runtime Form and a setup form (administration module).

For the runtime application I use this code

---

**Program.cs** - launch the runtime form

```
internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FrmMain());
    }
}
```

---

**FrmMain.cs** - initialize the UI and create the required instances

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    private BatchProcessor batchProcessor;
    private BatchManager batchManager;
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            batchProcessor = new BatchProcessor();
            sessionManager = new SessionManager();
            batchManager = new BatchManager(batchProcessor, sessionManager);
            // UpdateUI();              
            timerBatchPolling.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    private void FrmMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        timerBatchPolling.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            sessionManager.Logout();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    private void timerBatchPolling_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerBatchPolling.Enabled = false;
        batchManager.BatchPolling();
        // UpdateUI();
        timerBatchPolling.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

---

**BatchManager.cs** - ask for the next batch to process

```
internal class BatchManager
{
    private BatchProcessor batchProcessor;
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    public IBatch CurrentActiveBatch { get; private set; }

    public BatchManager(BatchProcessor batchProcessor, SessionManager sessionManager)
    {
        this.batchProcessor = batchProcessor;
        this.sessionManager = sessionManager;
        this.sessionManager.LoginToRuntimeSession();
    }

    public void BatchPolling()
    {
        CurrentActiveBatch = sessionManager.GetNextBatch();

        if (CurrentActiveBatch != null)
        {
            batchProcessor.ProcessBatch(CurrentActiveBatch);
        }
        else
        {
            sessionManager.Logout();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**BatchProcessor.cs** - process the batch

```
internal class BatchProcessor
{
    public void ProcessBatch(IBatch batch)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I just saw that it is also possible to run custom modules as services. I don't know how to register them or how to setup the code so I'm asking if there is a way to change my code to turn the module into a service instead of a forms application.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class derived from [ServiceBase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=netframework-4.8). The two relevant methods are `OnStart` and `OnStop`, read more about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceBase_OnStart_System_String___). Here is one example, note that `CustomModule` is one of my custom classes that takes care of logging into KC, processing batches, and more.

```cs
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // TODO: Add code here to start your service.
    cm = new CustomModule();
    cm.Login("", "");

    if (CustomModule.BatchNotificationEnabled == true)
    {
        cm.ListenForNewBatches();
    }
    else
    {
        cm.PollForNewBatches();
    }
}
```

For installing the service, you can add another class that derives from [Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer?view=netframework-4.8), but this is purely optional. However, I would recommend going the extra mile as this would allow you to install and uninstall your CM in the same style as all Kofax modules: `MyCustomModule.exe -install`.

Finally, in your `Program.cs`, check whether the user launched the module interactively or not:

```cs
if (Environment.UserInteractive)
{
    // run as module
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new RuntimeForm(args));
}
else
{
    // run as service
    ServiceBase.Run(new CustomModuleService());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I created a service project with your example code https://pastebin.com/uaTu0zeH, added the custom module to the administration module and installed the .exe on Windows as a service. But how would you automate it?

Comment: Sorry I mean if you have this module and run the batch queue and the module comes after the PDF generator, how do you launch it automatically? I still have to run it manually. And the service itself doesn't do anything.. so maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: A Windows service essentially runs the entire time after being started. Take a look at the `OnStart` method: here, either `ListenForNewBatches` or `PollForNewBatches` is invoked. The latter one is based on a simple timer - when it elapses, processing happens. Starting your module from Batch Manager (via the Run Button) does launch it as an application - this is where I show a Windows Form.